# How to create your own widget and reuse it in other activities android

Tags: android, android-widget

Right now I am in the process of creating a custom date picker on screen in a test app, but I wish to use it in multiple activities in my app, and it is complex enough that I just don't want to copy and past the code. I was wondering whether there is a way to nicely package it so I can reuse it easily.

Thanks for any help and info!

Answer (score 1):

Create whatever widget u intend to in a separate layout resource say "my_widget. xml"

And then use it another activity's xml (say activity_1.xml) by calling your widget in it, using
`<include layout=@layout/my_widget />`

Comment: The only problem with that is that I have over 300 lines of code to make it work... so how would I export that code along with the xml?

Comment: That cant be automatically performed, no help there...
U have to isolate the code manually..

Comment: I mean I understand that just putting the xml file in the main activity's can't hold code along with it, but I was wondering whether there was a way to say export the source code and layout and instantiate an instance of it in the main activity, or something like that.

Comment: You can export the collection of widgets in the way that u said...
But same can't be said about exporting code, not that I know of...

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom view (aka widget) following this ["Guide"](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html) implementing all your customizations you currently have to the view in your activity (as I understood) and then you can reuse your widget anywhere in this application or even on other applications (this is if you export this view into separate lib, and is subject for another discussion)